# If variable meets condition, replace value of another variable R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been looking at the various answers for similar issues, but can't see anything that quite answers my problem.

I have a large data table

| Number_X | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |

I want to replace the amount with 50 for those rows where Number_X == 1.
I've tried

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(Amount = replace(Amount, Number_X == 1, 50))
```

but it doesn't change the value for Amount. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# if then
df[ Number_X == 1, Amount := 50]
```

With large data, a `data.table` solution is most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue with using `replace()` but you can also try to use `if_else()`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

data <- tibble(
  Number_X = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L),
  Amount = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)
)

data %>% 
  mutate(Amount = replace(Amount, Number_X == 1, 50L))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   Number_X Amount
#>      <int>  <int>
#> 1        1     50
#> 2        2    100
#> 3        1     50
#> 4        3    100
#> 5        1     50
#> 6        2    100

data %>% 
  mutate(Amount = if_else(Number_X == 1, 50L, Amount))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   Number_X Amount
#>      <int>  <int>
#> 1        1     50
#> 2        2    100
#> 3        1     50
#> 4        3    100
#> 5        1     50
#> 6        2    100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Tip:  Use `dput()` with your data to share it more easily:

```r
dput(data)
#> structure(list(Number_X = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Amount = c(100L, 
#> 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
#> ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `tidyverse` approach:

```
data %>%
    mutate(Amount = ifelse(Number_X == 1, 50, Amount))
```

If you want almost the speed of `data.table` and the grammar of `dplyr`, you can consider `dtplyr`.